# java.lang.VerifyError while importing a jar for Android Project

Tags: java, android

I've created an Android Project that uses some JAR libs. I placed them in the folder /libs of the project and i'm calling some methods and classes from that libs and it's working properly with all classes and methods, except when i call one method from one class provided in one of the library, and this one tryes to create one object, in that moment it crash with

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/mypckg/commons/sip/agent/SipContext
at com.mypckg.commons.sip.agent.SipEndPointImpl.dial...................
```

So i can notice the problem is not with that jar (both SipEndPointImpl and SipContext belongs to the same jar), its only with the class SipContext.

Anybody can give me any hint to solve this? I've been looking at another questions and possible solutions, and nothing works.